# Install VB6 (Visual basic 6 ) without using wine

Tags: development, source-code

How to install VB6 in Ubuntu 17.10 without using a wine,
if Visual studio supports to VB6 codes then how to add extension in visual studio.

Comment: this is not duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) for VB.Net support Under Linux (at my knowledge, it's the closest solution to VB6 you'll get) (the IDE is called [Monodevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com)).

Comment: I had tryed it but Like visual basic it can not support Design GUI Forms

Answer (score 1):

To Design Form like in Visual basic as well as compile, run code, you can install **Gambas3**:

```
sudo apt-get install gambas3
```